# Android Proguard Compatiblity Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

Hello I'm writing an application that uses the compatibility library and i'm using a view pager in the app. I also am using an action bar library which i got from this link

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

my proguard.cfg file looks like this

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

#keep all classes that might be used in XML layouts
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.Fragment


#keep all public and protected methods that could be used by java reflection
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    public protected <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}


-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn org.htmlcleaner.*
```

and then my defualt.properties looks like this

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "build.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Project target.
target=android-8
android.library.reference.1=../android-actionbar/actionbar
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

However when i run to compile and sign my app i get a dialog that reads "Proguard returned with error code 1. See console."

So i take a look at my console which reads the following

```
[2011-11-01 01:48:39 - Test App] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2011-11-01 01:48:39 - Test App] proguard.ParseException: Unknown option 'Manager' in argument number 9
[2011-11-01 01:48:39 - Test App]    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:170)
[2011-11-01 01:48:39 - Test App]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:491)
```

But this doesn't really mean much to me and i don't know what i'm supposed to do to get this working? Any ideas i've used that proguard script before on an app that didn't use the compatibility library, however, the place i got that script from says it should work with the compatibility library but its not? Anyone have any ideas it would be greatly appreciated

**===EDIT===**

After removing the spaces from my build path i was able to get a bit farther but still failed with error 1 the console now had a new list of errors which looks like this now.

```
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp] Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find superclass or interface android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp] Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find referenced class android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp] Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find referenced class android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp] Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp]          or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:308)
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:210)
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:85)
[2011-11-01 14:01:20 - TestApp]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your project path contains spaces (and in this case the word Manager). The latest Android plugin for Eclipse (ADT R14) still has problems passing paths containing spaces to ProGuard. Alternative work-arounds:

- Use the command-line build based on Ant. The problem should be solved there.
- Install ProGuard 4.7 beta2 (or later). It is more lenient for missing quotes around file names containing spaces. You can just [download](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) the release and copy the jars from proguard/lib to android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib.
- Use a project path without spaces.

Comment: Please see my edit i removed the spaces form my project path as you suggested and was able to get a bit farther this time however still failed with error code 1 which printed some new messages to my console which i have edited my question with above. Thank you for the help from both of you so far

Comment: I also installed 4.7 beta2 as you suggested and got the same error and print out in the console as my edit above

Comment: The second error is caused by the Android Compatibility library referencing classes that only exist in recent versions of the Android API. In this case, that's ok, and you can let ProGuard accept it by adding "-dontwarn android.support.**".

Comment: thanks a ton got it to compile and is now proguarded thanks again for the help

Comment: @EricLafortune Thanks a ton for that -dontwarn android.support.** line. It would be awesome if you could include that in the answer also!

Comment: I am using proguard for obfuscating my android library. I am using action bar with fragments in my library project. How can I obfuscate the library file? I need specific lines of code for my application. Now, I am getting "can't find super
class or interface android.app.Fragment", "can't find superclass
 or interface android.app.ActionBar$TabListener" like errors.

Answer (score 0):

It could be few things, but what I did when I had that problem was:

- Update ADT plugin for Eclipse
- Install the latest version of ProGuard in android-sdk/tools/proguard
- Create a new project in Eclipse and copy all the classes and resources to the new project
- Configure proguard in the new project
- Export!

I don't know with the previous project didn't work, but what I know is that trick worked for me. I hope it helps